# Run JSP Page from batch file

Tags: jsp, batch-file

I am trying to run a JSP page in scheduled time. I have triend running it from batch file but it doesnt work greatly. It works once but then until now it didnt.

This what i tried [Please see this link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=677)

Comment: Is this going to run on Windows?  If so, look at using a Scheduled Task.

Comment: Yes on Windows. It doesnt work neither manual run the batch file nor scheduled tasks

Comment: You'll have to post your code and any error messages.

Comment: Already solve it :) Thanks

Comment: Sure, if you could please post your solution so that everyone benefits.  -thanks

Comment: I just do this in batch file. 

----  taskkill /IM chrome.exe
start chrome "localhost/AWLocal/?langBase=english" -----

Then make sure google chrome browser is not open.